# How to fix gap between text and table?

Tags: tables, spacing

This is my latex code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[t]%
\centering
\caption{Results \label{data}}%
\begin{tabular*}{450pt}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1data} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{2data} \\
M1 & M2 & M3 & M4 &&  M5 & M6 & M7 \\
\midrule
mean & 0.000  & &  && 0.0000  & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

In line citation, I use:

As in Table \ref{data}, the results...

Then, I got "As in Table 1 , the results..."
How to decrease gap between 1 and comma?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There seem to be **two** spacing issues: First, the excessive amount of space above and below the `table` environment; that's caused by the unnecessary use of a `center` environment to encase the `table` environment. As to your second question, about the cause of a gap between `1` and the comma: I'm afraid I'm unable to reproduce the issue on the basis of the code you've provided. Please provide compilable code that reproduces the issue you're trying to fix.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, please consider accepting it (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If the answer did not solve your question, you may want to leave a comment explaining why and/or edit your question to add additional detail that could help other people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You asked,

> How to fix gap between text and table?

Answer: Omit the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` directives, as they are directly responsible for the excessive amount of whitespace between the running text and the `table`.

Answer (score 0):

### Prior advise

To make it more easy to reproduce your document situation, please provide a fully copy-pastable [minimum work example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for further questions to be asked. As an example

1. I had to **guess** which tabular package you have used to format your
   table and
2. had to add some dummy text (in this case I used lipsum)

to **actually see** your problem(s).

### Remove white-space

You can get rid of the (unwanted additional) white-space before and after a float by omitting the environment `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`. For centered floats place the command `\centering` within the float you want to be centered (as you already did).

### Side notes

- Guessing that you wanted the table to fit the line width I recommend the use of the command `\linewidth` as the width parameter instead of a fixed value `450pt` as it will automatically fit your text width regardless of your document's actual size (especially useful if you experiment with the document width later on)
- Whilst using the placement flag "here" `h` you might want to consider putting a `\noindent` after your float to prevent latex to put an indent in front of the succeeding line. This is unnecessary for the other placement flags.

### Demonstration

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\section{Table here}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]%
\centering
\caption{Results \label{data1}}%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1data} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{2data} \\
M1 & M2 & M3 & M4 &&  M5 & M6 & M7 \\
\midrule
mean & 0.000  & &  && 0.0000  & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\noindent %if you prefer to not have an indent after the table
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Table top}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{table}[t]%
\centering
\caption{Results \label{data2}}%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1data} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{2data} \\
M1 & M2 & M3 & M4 &&  M5 & M6 & M7 \\
\midrule
mean & 0.000  & &  && 0.0000  & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\subsection{Table bottom}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{table}[b]%
\centering
\caption{Results \label{data3}}%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1data} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{2data} \\
M1 & M2 & M3 & M4 &&  M5 & M6 & M7 \\
\midrule
mean & 0.000  & &  && 0.0000  & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Table page}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{table}[p]%
\centering
\caption{Results \label{data4}}%
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep\fill}lcccccccc@{\extracolsep\fill}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1data} && \multicolumn{3}{c}{2data} \\
M1 & M2 & M3 & M4 &&  M5 & M6 & M7 \\
\midrule
mean & 0.000  & &  && 0.0000  & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Here you can see all placements variants. Hope it helps.